# action undefined at reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my component I fire my action:

```
 submitForm(e) {
  const language = e.target.value;
  this.props.actions.addLanguage(language, 'language', '2');
}
```

and connect to redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  UserDetails: state.UserDetails,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(UserActions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Screen1);
```

Actions/index:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export const addDetails = (age, gender, ethnicity) => ({
    type: types.ADD_DETAILS,
    age,
    gender,
    ethnicity,
});

export const addLanguage = (value, language, page) => ({
    type: types.ADD_LANGUAGE,
    value,
    language,
    page,
});

export const addAccessCode = (value, field) => ({
    type: types.ADD_ACCESSCODE,
    value,
    field,
});
```

UserDetails:

```
import {
  ADD_DETAILS,
  ADD_ACCESSCODE,
  ADD_LANGUAGE,
  ADD_DRINKS,
} from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
  id: 0,
  language: '',
  session: '',
  values: '',
  accessCode: '',
  age: 0,
  gender: '',
  ethnicity: '',
  drinkOften: '',
  drinkConcern: '',
};

export default function UserDetails(state = initialState, action) {
  debugger;
  return (dispatch, state) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_LANGUAGE:
        this.props.router.push(`${action.page}`);
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.field]: action.value,
        };

      case ADD_ACCESSCODE:
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.field]: action.value,
        };

      case ADD_DETAILS:
        return {
          ...state,
          ethnicity: action.ethnicity,
          gender: action.gender,
          age: action.age,
        };

      case ADD_DRINKS:
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.field]: action.value,
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

[image]

@Ravindra Ranwala I can get the action to fire with your suggestion, but its still undefined in the reducer, any ideas?

Using my debugger, the action is actually going in, but my reducer can't get past the thunk `return (dispatch, getState) => {`

Comment: Post your action `UserActions`, it looks like you aren't binding `addLanguage` to your component.

Comment: @Win does my reducer seem ok?

Comment: did you follow the below answer? Or is it still broken?

Comment: Yes, my action is returning the correct data, but the reducer is not getting past: `return (dispatch, getState) => {`

Comment: Get rid of that. Check answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Add return statement to your action, like this:

```
export const toggleTodo = id => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
    id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return (dispatch, getState) => { }`, you only need to switch statement inside your reducer. The below is an example of how your reducer should look as taken from the redux docs.

```js
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visibilityFilter: action.filter
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but where would I put my call to the router to change page? `this.props.router.push(`${action.page}`);`

Comment: You should not be trying to change routes in your reducer. This is a big no-no in terms of Redux. You should place this in your component after firing off the action creator `addLanguage`.